# How to Backup a Meteor Mongo Database?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

To create a backup of my mongo database, I am trying mongodump from my meteor console. The command successfully completes, but creates an empty folder under the dump folder. I use the command

```
mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor
```

So basically I am trying to backup my database for reactionecommerce.  My question is how to backup a meteor mongodb that is running locally? Thanks for any guidance of help.

Comment: do you have anything in your database ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to backup my reactionecommerce database.

Comment: can you go to mongo shell ? `mongo --port 3001` and `use meteor` then `show collections`. Is there any collection there?

Comment: Are you sure mongo db in running on that port? this is a very unusual problem

Comment: Yes. I am running it from 3001 port. I can see collections there when I give the command show collections. But when I issue mongodump command it just creates an empty folder.

Comment: What does `mongodump  --version` report? Is there any output when the `mongodump` command runs? Also, what version of Meteor is your application using (check `.meteor/release` in the app directory)?

Comment: Mongodump version is 2.6.10. mongodump  outputs the following  
                                    :vserver:/var/www/html/reaction$ mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor
connected to: 127.0.0.1:3001
2017-04-25T09:41:50.787+0530 DATABASE: meteor    to     dump/meteor

Comment: Can you try adding verbose logging to mongodump, add ``-vvvvv`` to your options

Comment: @helmy  2017-04-26T09:35:23.178+0530 creating new connection to:localhost:3001      
2017-04-26T09:35:23.178+0530 [ConnectBG] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG  
2017-04-26T09:35:23.180+0530 connected to server localhost:3001 (127.0.0.1)  
2017-04-26T09:35:23.180+0530 connected connection!  
connected to: localhost:3001  
2017-04-26T09:35:23.180+0530 DATABASE: meteor    to     dump/meteor  But still the dump/meteor folder is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the mongo version 2.6.10. I installed the latest 3.4.4 in my Ubuntu 64 machine following the instructions https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/  Now I am able to dump the data without any problem.